# How does one build a custom filter for wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have been trying to work out how to build a way to filter through a large number of wordpress posts using user input. I am not quite sure I understand how to get this to work. I'll explain what I know so far briefly and maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

So I understand I can use the wp_query($args) function to query my database and pass it my desired filtering arguments in order to get my desired result. Now because it has to be done by the user, I figured I could add a html form and did so like this

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="get">
<div class="form-group">
Price($) <input type="number" name="priceone" min="0" max="99" value="0"> to
<input type="number" name="pricetwo" min="0" max="300">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</div>
</form>
```

I then wrote the php code as follows to display my wordpress loop on my home page. I am using the form get method to store the variables as php variable which will be used as a variable in the wp_query loop if the user presses submit. However this doesn't work.

```
<?php 
  $minprice = $_GET["priceone"];
  $minprice = $_GET["pricetwo"];
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'food',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'=> array(
    'key' => 'price',
    'value' => array($minprice,$maxprice),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
 )
);

$thefood = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>

<?php if ( $thefood->have_posts() ) : while ( $thefood->have_posts() ) : $thefood->the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(full, array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no food matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The loop worked fine and displayed all posts before I added the new price variables into it. Now when I press submit, it just does nothing but adds the variables onto the end of the url saying ?pricemin=3 etc..

I feel like I am not understanding something. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To use 'meta_query' properly you actually need to pass and array of arrays.
Another problem with your code is that you defined minprice again instead of maxprice in the second line.

[Class Reference/WP Meta Query « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

```
<?php
    $minprice = $_GET["priceone"];
    $maxprice = $_GET["pricetwo"];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'food',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'=> array(
             array(
                 'key' => 'price',
                 'value' => array($minprice,$maxprice),
                 'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                 'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                )
            )
     );
```